# How to load Landsat imagery over ROI defined as a polygon rather than a point? GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, region

In google earth explorer you can load Landsat image around a roi. You can then conduct analysis on this image. I want to expand my region to cover a whole country or continent rather than just the small box defined by the roi. I've tried changing my roi to a polygon instead but this still only returns one image.

```js
// filtering the image collection
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
  .filterBounds(roi)    
  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')    
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')    
  .first());
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}, 'landsat');
```

[image: I need to expand the Landsat imagery to cover the whole country]

You can see in the image I have my region of interest on the coastline of Bangladesh. I need to expand the Landsat image to cover a larger area.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter the `ImageCollection` by `roi` you get an `ImageCollection` in which every image intersects the `roi`, but images still are individual images. So when you call `.first()` you are getting just one image out of the collection (that has more than one). What you need is a mosaic. There are many ways to make a mosaic, but the simpler one is to call `.mosaic()`

```js
// filtering the image collection
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
  .filterBounds(roi)    
  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')    
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')    
  .mosaic());
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}, 'landsat');
```

Comment: this works, but when I go to find the .median() for all of the images returned I get an error

    image.mosaic is not a function

Comment: when you apply a reducer (median, mean, etc) over an `ImageCollection` you get an `Image` as the result, and you can only mosaic collections, not images. Reducing the image would be another way of making a mosaic